# Is there a way to minify css classNames?

Tags: node.js, webpack, css-modules

I wanna make some obfuscation and minification by changing my css class-names. As I don't think this is a right way to minify it by myself, so I'm using css modules with

```
getLocalIdent: MinimalClassnameGenerator({ length: 1 })
//where MinimalClassnameGenerator is webpack-minimal-classnames
```

and it works at css side, class names is minified. But unfortunately at output.bundle.js I've found lines like this

```
 const N = { class: "super-puper-class" },
[
          "__cssModules",
          {
            $style: {
              "super-puper-class": "J",
```

It means that only css side is minified and somebody could know real class name after compilation. Is there a way to minify and obfuscate classNames right?

Comment: Obfuscating class names is not worth doing.  It's not going to deter anyone from anything.  It might make troubleshooting or debugging more difficult too.

Comment: Thanks, but I mean for the production version when everything is debugged))

Comment: Do you really think you're never tracking down problems in production? Some problems only occur in production, particularly when you're running entirely different HTML/CSS in production from dev because you obfuscated it all. And, the test environment has to run the obfuscated code too so you may have to track down problems there too. But, the main reason for avoiding the obfuscating of class names is that it adds an additional complication and serves no useful purpose.

Comment: It reduces css size and makes scraping harder (if class change at every build)